# Create a Constraint to check the value of a column

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a table called (art_almacen) that contains articles (carticle) in warehouse (calmacen), now, how I can check (using constraints) that any warehouse has a duplicate article? for example:

If I have a warehouse with Id=3, and it has 3 articles (1,2,3), when I try to add another article, for example 3, block me, because warehouse 3 already has an article 3

This is my Table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.art_almacen
(
  cart_almacen integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_art_almacen'::regclass),
  calmacen integer NOT NULL,
  carticulo integer NOT NULL,
  cant numeric(11,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_art_almacen PRIMARY KEY (cart_almacen)
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index
)
```

Using PostgreSQL

Comment: if you create a primary key it will take of not allowing duplicates

Comment: I cant relate title to the body...

Comment: But a primary key cant have duplicates values, and if i add a article 3 in warehouse 1 this is not a duplicate value . . . @VaoTsun

Comment: the create a composite PK - on two columns. but I don't see column "warehouse", and title is very misleading

Comment: @VaoTsun Title Edited, (im using google traslate), How i can check the value of (carticle) by (calmacen) value? (i need make imposible have the same article (carticle) in the same warehouse (calmacen)

Comment: he contestado con ejemplos - mire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite PK:

```
t=# CREATE TABLE public.art_almacen
(
  cart_almacen serial,--integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_art_almacen'::regclass),
  calmacen integer NOT NULL,
  carticulo integer NOT NULL,
  cant numeric(11,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_art_almacen PRIMARY KEY (cart_almacen,calmacen )
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE sistema_index
)
;
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into public.art_almacen select 1,1,1,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into public.art_almacen select 1,2,1,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into public.art_almacen select 2,1,1,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into public.art_almacen select 2,2,1,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into public.art_almacen select 1,2,1,1;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "fk_art_almacen"
DETAIL:  Key (cart_almacen, calmacen)=(1, 2) already exists.
```

Comment: Well is the biggest Solution!, but i have one more question, why do you use serial? is better?

Comment: no - just a shortcut to `integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_art_almacen'::regclass)` - look the https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need an [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) on two columns (wirehouse, article). In this case DB will not allow you to have two rows with the same combination of warehouse and article. Like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  a integer,
  wirehouse integer,
  article integer,
  UNIQUE (wirehouse, article)
);
```